# Groovy: Add node to NodeChildren

Tags: xml, groovy, addition, nodes

I am new to Groovy and somehow struggling with the syntax. I have an object of type NodeChildren (in groovy.util.slurpersupport) which represent an XML structure like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.camerontec.catalys.node</groupId>
  <artifactId>catalys-node-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

All I wanna do it add another dependency to it, for example:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jdom</groupId>
  <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I must be fairly simple but for some reason I cannot figure it out. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with XmlSlurper (if you turn off namespaces so XmlSlurper doesn't prefix all non-namespaced tags with `tag0`) -- I removed 2 of the original deps to save room in this answer

```
import groovy.xml.*

def original = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.camerontec.catalys.node</groupId>
  <artifactId>catalys-node-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>'''

def newDep = '''<dependency>
  <groupId>jdom</groupId>
  <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>'''

def newNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText( newDep )
def oldNode = new XmlSlurper( false, false ).parseText( original )

oldNode.dependencies.appendNode( newNode )
String xmlStr = XmlUtil.serialize( new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { mkp.yield oldNode } )
println xmlStr
```